# What is more efficient one match OR multiple match piped by with

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a huge two column csv, almost 100,000,000 rows in the format of source_node and destination_node. Also I have a graph in my neo4j db where all nodes and some relationships are present. Now I am trying to build all the remaining relationships using this csv. I can do this using either of the two queries but I want to know which would be more efficient and correct. My queries are

```
load csv with headers from 
"file:///C:/Users/neo4j_workspace/graph_db/import/dependency_filename.csv" as table 
match (a:Job{name:table.sourcenodename}) 
with a, table 
match (b:Job{name:table.destinationnodename})  
with a, b 
merge (a)-[:with]->(b)
```

OR

```
load csv with headers from 
"file:///C:/Users/neo4j_workspace/graph_db/import/dependency_filename.csv" as table 
match (a:Job{name:table.sourcenodename}) ,(b:Job{name:table.destinationnodename}) 
merge (a)-[:with]->(b)
```

Comment: You can find that out for yourself by using PROFILE before the query...Also creating a constraing on :Job(name) will be very useful

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the first method of explicit match statements.

Comma separated match statement still counts as the same one. While this would have no difference if there are no relationships between (a) and (b), this may change the meaning of the match statement when there might be per-existing relationships (considering you are using a merge statement for the [:with] relationship) and may make the query much slower in this case.

Another useful thing you could do would be use the following statement as a prefix before the load csv command to batch load your data for performance optimization

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 //change number based on your specific needs
```